# Assigning a class to the <div> parent of an image

Tags: jquery, html

ETA - Solution found. Nice work Stack Overflow beauties!! What would I do without you ;) ;)

I'm building a carousel, some items have images, others don't. I need to be able to target the items without images for styling, so I'm trying to add a class to the div that wraps the image if that makes sense?

What I have is this : 
**For items with images:**

```html
<div class="carousel-item active" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
      <span>Day 1</span>
      <img src="*example image*" class="img-responsive" alt="words here" width="380" height="226" title="words here">
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

**For items without images :**

```html
<div class="carousel-item" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
      <span>Day 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

And what I'm trying to do using jquery is add the class 'noImg' to the div 'carousel-item' what I've tried is many variations of this sort of thing :

```js
$("div.carousel-item").addClass("noImg");
if ($(this).hasClass('.img-responsive')) {
  ("div.carousel-item").removeClass("noImg")
};
```

I've tried variations of `.children .parent` I've tried doing it the other way around and doing `.find` on `image-responsive` and adding classes that way.

Any suggestions of the 'you dope, you're missing this obvious thing' would very much be appreciated, Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your jQuery code in the example is that `this` has no context. It would related to the `window`, not the `.carousel-item` as you seem to be expecting.

Also note that your HTML is invalid. `li` elements *must* be contained within a parent `ul`.

To make this work you can simply use a combination of `:not()` and `:has()` to find the containers which *do not* have an `img` element, like this:

```js
$('.carousel-item:not(:has(img))').addClass('noImg');
```

```css
.noImg, 
.noImg a {
  color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-item active" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
        <span>Day 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
        <span>Day 2</span>
        <img src="*example image*" class="img-responsive" alt="words here" width="380" height="226" title="words here">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item active" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
        <span>Day 3</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a babe, thank you :) there is a parent ul, surrounding the entire carousel the carousel does run fine, it's just the css I'm struggling with. 
Thank you, I'll give this a go :) xx

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help

Comment: Works perfectly :) You're a star <3

Answer (score 0):

Working example, see console.output:

```js
$('.carousel-item').each(function (idx) {
  if ($(this).find('img').length)
    $(this).removeClass('noImg')
  else
    $(this).addClass('noImg')
  console.log('Div ' + idx + ' hasClass noImg: ' + $(this).hasClass('noImg'))
})
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item active" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
      <span>Day 1</span>
      <img src="*example image*" class="img-responsive" alt="words here" width="380" height="226" title="words here">
    </a>
  </li>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
      <span>Day 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could something like this, find an element within the children of an element and if it exist then then change the class of the parent

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var hasImg=$("div.carousel-item").find("img");

  if(hasImg.lenght>0) 
    {
        $("div.carousel-item").removeClass("noImg");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use this working code:

```
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
            <span>Day 1</span>
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="img-responsive" alt="words here" width="350" height="150" title="words here">
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item" style="width: 157.4px; margin-right: 2px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="innerTabLink" rel="XYZ">
            <span>Day 1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

and script

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {

            $('.img-responsive').parents('.carousel-item').addClass('new-class');
        }
    );
```

Comment: Awesome you're a star :) :) Thank you xx

Comment: Please set the answer as correct if you are satisfied. ;D